# How to wrap startActivityForResult using RxJava?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, rx-android

How do I start and receive the result from a `Activity` inside the same 'Reactive chain'? Is it possible to wrap the `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult`; if so how would I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a wrapper class that holds the result and request codes, and the intent. Let's call it Result

You can create a PublishSubject field in your Activity class.  Let's call it subject.

Then you just call subject.onNext(new Result(requestCode, resultCode, data)); inside your onActivityResult method.

And finally you chain the subject the way you would an observable to your RX chain using a flatMap or some other operator based on what you need.

Sorry for poor formatting, I'm on my phone.